# Running hot-key based on its Language in TextMate

Tags: macos, textmate

When I have a command A of OBjective-C that has key Command-Shift-R, and command B of Text mode that has the same hotkey, I have a pop up with the activation key of Command-Shift-R regardless of the mode I'm in.

How can I make it mode sensitive? I mean, how can I run Objective-C command only when I'm in Objective-C mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a *scope* to the command.

Open *Bundles » Bundle Editor » Bundle Editor...* and select the command you want to change.

Look for the command in the *Objective-C* category and select it, then enter a scope to the lower right, probably `source.objc, source.objc++`. Then the command will be available anywhere in files with Objective-C highlighting.

Check out the other commands in the *Objective-C* category for more specialized scopes, e.g. *Documentation for Selector* and its scope `meta.bracketed.objc | meta.function.objc`.